# Is it possible to track which users create other users? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I have a tiered role model for users, Super User > Admin > other users. (I'm using cancan to implement this)
The super user should be able to access all other users' profiles, but the admin should be able to access the user profiles only of the users that he creates. 
Is it possible to assign ownership of created users like one might do for posts/comments? 
My abilities file currently looks as follows:

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new
  if user.status == "Super User"  
    can :manage, :all
  elsif user.status == "Admin"
    can :create, User           
    can :show, User, :id => user.id
    can :update, User, :id => user.id

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you just need to keep track of it in your database. For example, you might add a "creator_id" field in your User database, which stores the ID of the creating user (Admin or Super User).

In your User model, you can do something like:

```
belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
```

And then in your Ability:

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new
  if user.status == "Super User"  
    can :manage, :all
  elsif user.status == "Admin"
    can :create, User           
    can [:show, :update], User, :id => user.id
    can [:show, :update], User, :creator_id => user.id
  end
end
```

I've combined your show/update lines, so that the admin can see or update him/herself. Then I added another can line so that an admin can show/update any user who was created by the current user.

edit:

Wherever you are creating the user, I'm guessing `current_user` would be an Admin, yes? You can just set the user's `creator` property then:

```
user = User.new(name: 'Foo Bar') # or however you are doing it
user.creator = current_user
user.save
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I think I'm grasping the concept (angry it was something so simple, thank you) I'm having a bit of trouble now creating a creator_id when I create a user. I've added a column in my Users database for the creator_id, but am a little unsure of how to store a value.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still working on it. I still can't quite get it to do what I want, but you were extremely helpful in giving me a push in the right direction

Comment: So if you're still willing to help me, I've made the changes you've suggested, and currently can only update the current user. I've checked my database, and it successfully assigned the current user's id to the creator_id field. However, when I try to have an admin edit a user he created, I'm still facing the problem of denial of permissions (though my line for this now reads: can [:manage], User, :creator_id => user.id)
Any thoughts?